# trouble installing Glade Interface Designer, Glade doesn't launch?

Tags: interface, installation, designer, launch, glade

it's like my third time installing Glade Interface Designer, never had trouble before, but now when i type `glade-3` on terminal it send me back:

```
glade-3: error while loading shared libraries: libgladeui-1.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed just like before, it is just in a different computer but exactly same OS. 
Glade Version 3.8.5, OS Debian Wheezy 7.5. Already installed gtk2 and glib. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick update...

> apt-get install libgladeui-1-dev

Didn't work for me... but

```
sudo apt-get install libgladeui*
```

Did the trick (after rebooting).  Nb: I'm on Xenial/16.04

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I just fixed it by randomly typing in terminal `apt-get install libgladeui-1-dev`.